# How to use default style values of 'Tabs on the Left' for Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using 'Tabs on the left' snippet of Bootstrap

[image]

This is the code

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#lA" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lB" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lC" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="lA">
                  <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="lB">
                  <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="lC">
                  <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I am using this [ON MY WEBSITE](http://www.carantina.com)

If you check the menu item **'PRODUCTS'** you will see that tabs doesn't look same as bootstrap page.

The reason is obvious, since this is a drop-down menu and the tab is a **li** tag under **ul** and another **li** , it inherits the css values of them and shows this.

[image]

I have tried everything to override this values to default bootstrap values but I could not succeed.

Comment: you could add !important at the end. But it won't be the best approach. Just use firebug to see where the styles come from and delete them.

Comment: @Johnny000 I am trying but I couldn't find the root of it. It still shows the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you are looking for: http://www.bootply.com/68857

You are using a mega menu and so you need to over-ride styling that's coming from that.

If you look at the bottom of the CSS pane in my example you will see I've restored the default tab styling plud a few modifications.

Hope this helps!